# How can I right-click an HTML link, choose "Print" and bypass the printer selection menu?

Tags: windows, printing, right-click, bypass, html-files

Is it possible in Windows 2008 R2 to be able to right click an HTML link (with IE as default, Chrome doesn't have the "Print" option on the right-click) and completely bypass the printer selection menu and print straight from the default printer?

I tried right-click printing pdf's, various image files, csv's, xls's, etc., all worked fine, printed without the printer selection menu. This only occurs with HTML links.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the HTML element that has no Print option and see it's value it will probably empty.

A right-click on the browser is an event which triggers an action based on the context it is called from. If you click on a link tag which has no value itself, you are not going to get a print option in the menu because there is nothing to print. This is a likely scenario, you can also read up on the "Media" HTML attribute. It has a Print option which helps the browser know what stuff is for.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Okay, here is the answer.

A right click on the browser is an event which triggers an action based on the context it is called from.
If you click on a link tag which has no value itself, you are not going to get a print option in the menu because there is nothing to print.

This is a likely scenario, 
you can also read up on the "Media" HTML attribute.
It has a Print option which helps the browser know what stuff is for.

Comment: @PetarAtanasov - You should edit your answer instead of submitting comment.